# I get the Error: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a search bar that connects to my tableview, but when I run it, I get an error that says, 'Fatal error: Index out of range' when clicking on the search bar on line 'return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count'. How do I fix this? Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    struct data {
        var sectionTitle = String()
        var rowTitles = [String]()
    }

    var dataArray = [data(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]),
        data(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2"]),
        data(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["row 1"])
       ]
    var searchArray = [(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]()
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count
        } else {
            return dataArray[section].rowTitles.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if searching {
        return searchArray.count
        } else {
        return dataArray[section].sectionTitle
        }
    }
}


extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            searching = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            searching = true
            searchArray = dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle == searchBar.text})
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you should have

```
var searchArray = [data]()
```

then

```
extension ViewController2: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            searching = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            searching = true
           searchArray = dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) || $0.rowTitles.map{$0.lowercased()}.contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) })
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I run this I get an error that says 'Fatal error: Index out of range'.

Comment: what you are searching ?

Comment: I am searching for the different row titles, but when I try to use the search bar, I get directed to the error.

Comment: I've been making sure that the syntax and spelling is correct and it still doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: index out of range means you are accessing element which is not in the array

Comment: `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }` update this method with searching and non searching

Comment: The search bar now allows for text to be input but does not display any results. I've updated the code to match what I have.

Comment: search section 1

Comment: it results on exact match

Comment: Is there a way to make the search by a .prefix?

Comment: what do you mean by prefix ?

Comment: when you start typing a letter in, the tableview will show all of the values that start with a letter. For example you type in "r" and it shows "row 1", "row 2" and more.

Comment: this search is on section number .. not on row

Comment: thanks. one last thing: when I type in section 2 for example, it pulls up the list of rows but has the header section 1. How would I solve this? also, in your solution it is on section number, can I make the search on section and row?

Comment: thanks. and as for when I type in section 2 for example, it pulls up the list of rows but has the header section 1. How would I solve this?